# Using template to set a variable in chef

Tags: templates, chef-infra

new to chef and trying to pass a long list of variables to a batch file run. Have thought of writing a list of these in a template and calling the template in the recipe i.e:

options = template "optionstemplate"

How does one set a variable using hashes from a template of in chef? Please do let me know if this is possible of if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically doable, this is very hard and not recommended. You should instead write some Ruby code to generate the options string you need. Maybe something like:

```
options = ''
node['mythingy']['options'].each do |key, value|
  options << " --#{key}=#{value}"
end
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, will attempt to go via this approach as on further research it does seem much easier. Thank you!!!